# Adding items dynamically to accordion layout

Tags: javascript, extjs, accordion

I have created a panel with accordion layout. I am unable to add dynamic items within the panel. The value of `items` is static as shown below. Please help me resolving this issue.

Below is the code:

```
var panel = new Ext.panel{
  scroll: "vertical"
  layout{
     type: "accordian"
   }

   items: [{xtype:"panel", title:"123", html:"123"}]
}
```

How to include dynamic values to items based on JSON?

Comment: What is happening as a result of your code? How are you attempting to create dynamic items?

Comment: By the way, the layout is `accordion` not `accordian`

Comment: Don't use the `new` keyword to create a instance! Use `Ext.create` for that!

Answer (score 4):

You can add items to any given container dynamically with:

```
var panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
  title: 'Hello World',
  layout{ type: 'accordion' },
  renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
var items = [{title:"123", html:"123"},{title:"456", html:"456"}];

panel.add(items);
```

**Edit:**
Look in the [Touch1.1 docs](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext.Container-method-add) for more examples.

Ext Touch 1.1 example:

```
var cnt = new Ext.Container({});
var items = [{title:"123", html:"123"},{title:"456", html:"456"}];

cnt.render(document.body);
cnt.add(items);
cnt.doLayout();
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply... I am using sencha touch 1.1 for building this application. Ext.create('',{}) is supported in sencha touch 2.x but not getting supported in sencha touch 1.x. Please help me by providing other alternative. Thanks in advance.